# Android Customize ActionBar Color?

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, customization, android-theme

What i want? I want to make the ActionBar color customizable, users can select a color from a list of colors and the ActionBar color will be changed to their selected color.

What i have done? I have a class named SettingsActivity in which i take color choice from user. The color they select is stored in SharedPreferences. The color user selected is getting stored in SharedPreferences and then i restart the application through an intent the color change take place. Everything is working as it should.

But there is a problem whenever i start the application for a small interval of time the app shows the default color that i have at styles.xml in values v-14 folder and then the color changes to user selected color. How can i eliminate this bug?

I'm also attaching the code of styles.xml. If any other detail or code is required then do let me know i will provide that as well and I am using Navigation Drawer Fragments.

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     API 14 theme customizations can go here. 
</style>
 -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
      <item name="android:background">#f39c12</item> 
   </style>
 </resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this for change action bar color:_

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable("COLOR"));
```

**OR use this one**

```
    ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffFEBB31"));
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
```

Thanks

Comment: i have already done that part, my problem is my application shows the default color lets say blue color at applicaion start up and then after some milliseconds changes the color to user selection lets say white color. If user has already selected his theme to be white when the application is restarted the application will show blue color for some milliseconds and then change the action bar color to white. i want to eliminate that milliseconds interval that show blue color i want the app to start with white color